# How to set phtml file in specific area Magento 1.9 using an Observer

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, cart, event-observer

I'm trying to set/ display a template file instead of the default messaging in Magento 1.9 using an Observer when the checkout loads but I cannot get the phtml file to show up and I don't know why??

Here is the event that I am observing:

```
    <events>
        <controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_index>
            <observers>
                <event_handler>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>my_module/observer</class>
                    <method>myCustomMethod</method>
                </event_handler>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_cart_index>
    </events>
```

Next in the Observer I would like to add a phtml file using layout update xml so I have them defined in my module folder:

```
<custom_module_template>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="core/template" name="global_messages" template="custom/module/template.phtml" />
    </reference>
</custom_module_template>
```

In my Observer I call:

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getUpdate()->addHandle('custom_module_template');
```

And I can see the handler is added but nothing is being show on the page. I'm trying to add this template file in the same area as the `global_messages` block would be.

Am I using the correct apporach?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i noticed in your code is that the block type is not **core/messages** for the 'global_messages' (reference is *app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/page.xml* where the 'global_messages' block is defined).

However, if you check the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php` class, you will see that this block doesn't use a template file, it is rendered by default and that the HTML is generated in the `getGroupedHtml()` method.

So basically, **you can change the HTML by creating a rewrite for this class and overwriting the `getGroupedHtml()` method.** **Just be aware that this class is also used in the admin side** so overwriting it will impact the admin messages as well.

---

***LE:*** if you are not very keen on rewriting the class I suggest another approach which would impact only the frontend and you might be lucky for it to work from the first try: copy the ***layout/page.xml*** file in your own theme and replace the 'global_messages' line with a line referencing a custom block class which inherits the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Messages.php` and a custom template file, then in the template file specifically call and print the `$this->getGroupedHtml()` method result.

OR

Use the same approach as described above with a custom block class, only don't overwrite the entire 'page.xml', instead, reference the 'root' block in a custom layout file, invoke the remove block action, then re-add the global messages but this time with your custom block type and template. Something like this:

```xml
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="root">
            <remove name="global_messages" />
            <block type="custom_module/custom_messages_block" name="global_messages" template="custom_module/page/global_messages.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to avoid a rewrite hence using an Observer, I only need to set a template where a the global_messages should be.

Comment: I see. Check the update in my answer, maybe it helps. It's not using an observer, tho'.

Comment: Botean I see it. However, I need to set this template in an area where the global messages are shown but without rewriting the messages class.

Comment: Well, you aren't rewriting the messages class (as described in my later edit) :) you are replacing it :)